# Error in simple array... How to fix

Tags: java, syntax-error

This gives me an error of:

> Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided.

How to fix it?

```
static String names[] = new String[8]{
 "Global Mining Technologies",
 "Advanced Mine Group",
 "Hi-Tech Mining Industrial",
 "Victory Mining Co.",
 "Miners of Land Inc.",
 "Space-Age Mining Industries",
 "EasyMine Co.",
 "C.R.A.F.T Mining"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly as the error mentions.
Either you specify dimensions and don't initialize inline, or you don't specify dimension and are allowed to initialize elements.

Use this idiom instead:

```
static String names[] = {
 "Global Mining Technologies",
 "Advanced Mine Group",
 "Hi-Tech Mining Industrial",
 "Victory Mining Co.",
 "Miners of Land Inc.",
 "Space-Age Mining Industries",
 "EasyMine Co.",
 "C.R.A.F.T Mining"};
```